# Understanding web services, architecture example

Tags: web-services, web-applications

So consider following idea.

I want to build simple **web application** where visitors can posts anything(jokes, pictures etc). Each post will be saved in data base and each post will have like/dislike option.
No need for Login and Registration system.

After that i want to build simple **android application** which need communication with mentioned data base in that way android application will receive only posts with most likes(for example, *per day* android application will show 10 posts with most votes and nothing more)

I read many answers here on topic "difference between web application and web services" and i dont understand it well.

First can i use web services here to pull data from data base(XML) and to show that through android application?

If i can, how i understand web services through this example is following:
**1.** Web application is intended for users and for populating data base with posts.
**2.** Web service doesn't know anything about web application, and web application doesn't know anything about web service. These two are standalone entities.
**On other hand web service will use data that is saved from web application into data base?**
**3.** Web service is intended for some another system in that way he will send some data in particular format to that system?(In another words it is not inteneded for users like web application)
**4.** I need to implement web service through different methods that knows how to connect to data base and know how to pull data, and know how to convert that data in particular format and send it back to client. (which is android application in this case)? Android application then will parse that data and show it to the user of the app.
**5.** Physical Web application, web service and DB can be on different places.

So something like this?
[image]

So is this wrong approach and how this work? Can you suggest through image some another architecure or any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using expose a REST API, so it can be reused by android and web applications.

Your business logic and database connection will be on the API.

A technology that can help is Microsoft Web API and ASP.NET MVC, makes easy to reuse code between API and MVC application.

Comment: So, if i get it right, idea is to create something like "API" controller in web application with appropriate actions which will return data(in format of JSON/XML) from data base? In that case that controller is something like web service?

Then android application can retrieve data with request something like webapplication.com/api/getSomething
?

Comment: Exactly they are called **"RESTFUL Web services"** based on HTTP protocol. You can have an "API controller" is almost the same as a "MVC Controller" in that way you can call the controller actions (routes Ex: webapplication.com/api/getSomething) from a web page, ajax or a mobile application. Because almost every platform has an HTTP  client.